# How to set page size with account summitries list in Google analytics admin api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

The [Method: accountSummaries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/accountSummaries/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A1%7D) method has an optional parm called page size

> pageSize   integer
>
> The maximum number of AccountSummary resources to return. The service may return fewer than this value, even if there are additional pages. If unspecified, at most 50 resources will be returned. The maximum value is 200; (higher values will be coerced to the maximum)

In the following example if i dont set page size then the code runs and get all the rows. However if i do set page size then I get an error that this option does not exist

```
from google.analytics.admin import AnalyticsAdminServiceClient

# pip install google-analytics-admin

CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = 'C:\credentials.json'

from google_auth_oauthlib import flow

def list_accounts(credentials=None):
    """
    Lists the available Google Analytics accounts.

    Args:

    """


    # Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
    # specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
    client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

    # Make the request
    results = client.list_account_summaries(page_size = 1)  # ERROR HERE

    # Displays the configuration information for all Google Analytics accounts
    # available to the authenticated user.
    print("Result:")
    for account in results:
        print(account)



def get_credentials():
    """Creates an OAuth2 credentials instance."""

    appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"],
    )
    # TODO(developer): Update the line below to set the `launch_browser` variable.
    # The `launch_browser` boolean variable indicates if a local server is used
    # as the callback URL in the auth flow. A value of `True` is recommended,
    # but a local server does not work if accessing the application remotely,
    # such as over SSH or from a remote Jupyter notebook.
    launch_browser = True
    if launch_browser:
        appflow.run_local_server()
    else:
        # note yes this is deprecated.  It will work if you change the redirect uri in the url given you from urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
        # to http://127.0.0.1  The client library team needs to fix this.
        appflow.run_console()
    return appflow.credentials



def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    list_accounts(credentials)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> TypeError: list_account_summaries() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page_size'

I have tried pagesize, page_size, pageSize nothing seems to work I have also dug around in the github project and it seems it should be page_size but its not working.

## Note on Alpha and beta versions.

alpha and beta versions apear to have allowed for

```
request = client.ListAccountSummariesRequest()
request.page_size = 1
results = client.list_account_summaries(request)
```

with the full version this results in

> AttributeError: 'AnalyticsAdminServiceClient' object has no attribute 'ListAccountSummariesRequest'

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `page_size` in a `request` and set that as the parameter of `list_account_summaries`.

```
    request = {
        'page_size' : 1
    };
    results = client.list_account_summaries(request=request)
```

FYI: The `list_account_summaries` method will return a `ListAccountSummariesAsyncPager` (see  https://googleapis.dev/python/analyticsadmin/latest/admin_v1alpha/analytics_admin_service.html?highlight=list_account_summaries#google.analytics.admin_v1alpha.services.analytics_admin_service.pagers.ListAccessBindingsAsyncPager ). It will automatically fetch next pages for you.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear I am using the full release.   The alpha version the beta version works the same.   I am using the full release which doesn't appear to have ListAccountSummariesRequest.   I have edited my question to reflect this.   Do you have a solution for the full version?

Comment: I don't believe there is a stable version of the Analytics Admin API currently.  I've updated my answer to not use the alpha or beta version. It should work.